# Does creating a reference to parent object within the child object cause a cyclic relationship?

Tags: javascript

I know that getting the parent object of the current object is an old topic but, I have a question about the solution that is provided to solve this problem. Most of the answers that I have found say to simply create a property within the child object which is set to the parent object. If creating a reference to the parent object within the child object creates a cyclic relationship then how can this be a valid solution? Here is an example that illustrates this solution -

```
var obj = {
    innerObj: {},
    setParent: function(){
        this.innerObj.parent = this;
    }
};
obj.setParent();
```

The result of this will create an object which looks like this -

obj.innerObj.parent.innerObj.parent.innerObj... and just keeps going.

I have been working on finding a different solution. If we have control over how the object is created then one possible solution could be something like this -

```
var obj = function(that){
    that = that || this;
    var o = { getParent: function(){ return that; } };
    return o;
};
```

Now when you create a new object you can simply pass in the object that you want to be returned as the parent and no cyclic type of relationship is created.

Example:

```
var myObj = obj();
myObj.myInnerObj = obj(myObj);

var parentObj = myObj.myInnerObj.getParent(); // parentObj = myObj
```

Comment: Why do you think a cyclic relationship is a problem? Nothing is automatically following all the links between the objects.

Comment: @Barmar That is another good question. And I think, from the little I have read, that this type of cyclic relationship can have several potential issues. Here is a link to a page which specifically talks about why this can be a bad thing. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references

Comment: It's not inherently bad, it just has the possibility to be bad. Like many options in programming, it depends on how you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer simply, yes it does cause a cyclic relationship. However this is not a problem in any way. As long as you don't then write a function which tries to crawl down those objects infinitely, there is no issue with this pattern.

One example of this is [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), which has collections made up of models. Each model has a reference to the collection, which has the models inside of them etc.

This works perfectly fine in practice.

Comment: Okay, I am going to accept this answer because I have found several posts which point out the usefulness of a cyclic relationship in certain situations. And, I still think that in this particular situation, when simply creating a new object and wanting to be able to easily get its parent a more safe solution (like my example) would be just as easy and does not need a cyclic relationship to make it work. But, I have definitely been known to be wrong :).